# Ruby on Rails изменение схемы базы данных "на лету"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть ли возможность изменять схему базы данных на основании пользовательского ввода и применять её без перезагрузки веб сервера?

В качестве примера:

1. Пользователь через форму создает новую сущность.
2. После отправки формы на сервер создается соответствующая модель проводится миграция.
3. Изменения доступны остальным пользователям без перезагрузки веб сервера.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Есть обходной путь. Строится на паре таблиц definitions и instances.

Первая (definitions) это описание создаваемых классов, в ней два столбца (помимо id) - name:string и structure:text. В классе сериализируем attr_list, это будет хэш, ключами будут имена атрибутов, значениями их тип.

Вторая таблица (instances) это собственно объекты.Она содержит столбцы id, definition_id:integer, instance_id:integer и values:text. Аналогично используем serialized values для хранения объекта. В ней values это хэш из первой таблицы согласно выбранного типа объекта, ключи остаются, а вот значения меняются на фактические значения полей объекта.

То есть, сначала мы определяем на лету некий "класс", сохраняем его в первую таблицу, а потом строим форму и уже из нее формируем новый объект, который сохраняется во второй таблицу. Остается только обеспечить стандартные методы CRUD для манипуляции с этими объектами, но это уже дело техники.

```
class CreateTables < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :definitions do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text :structure
    end

    create_table :instances do |t|
      t.references :definition, null: false
      t.integer :instance_id, null: false
      t.text :values
    end

    add_index :instances, :definition_id
  end
end

class Definition < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :structure, Hash
end

class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :values, Hash
end
```

Comment: Пробовал подобное решение, но при больших наборах данных запросы начинают крайне медленно выполняться, хочется сделать что-то вроде настройки (пусть она будет долгой).

Answer (score 0):

Можно только хранить динамические данные:

- В Postgre использовать тип json/jsonb
- Dynamic fields в MongoDB